# onCreate in abstract parent activity no called in kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

I declared a child of MapActivity:

```
class RecordingActivity : MapActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        Log.d("RecirdingActivity", "InitializeMap") //called
    }

    override fun getView(): Int {
        return R.layout.activity_recording
    }
}
```

I make a call to start this activity from my main activity:

```
fab.setOnClickListener {
            Log.d("MainActivity", "fabClick") //called
            startActivity(intentFor<RecordingActivity>())
        }
```

and I have the abstract activity:

```
abstract class MapActivity: AppCompatActivity(), OnMapReadyCallback {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?, persistentState: PersistableBundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState, persistentState)
        setContentView(getView())
        initializeMap()
        Log.d("MapActivity", "InitializeMap")//not called
    }
}
```

and **onCreate method of this activity is never called**

I traced it with a debugger and I had the same result.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You want the `onCreate()` overload with just the one `Bundle` parameter. No `PersistableBundle`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

there seems to be two solutions:

1. maybe the `onCreate` you actually want to override in `MapActivity` has the signature [`onCreate(android.os.Bundle)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/app/AppCompatActivity.html#onCreate(android.os.Bundle)):

   ```
   abstract class MapActivity: AppCompatActivity(), OnMapReadyCallback {

       override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
           super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
           setContentView(getView())
           initializeMap()
           Log.d("MapActivity", "InitializeMap")
       }
   }
   ```
2. the documentation of the [`onCreate(android.os.Bundle, android.os.PersistableBundle)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onCreate(android.os.Bundle,%20android.os.PersistableBundle)) method that is being overridden in `MapActivity` suggests that `persistableMode` for the activity in the `AndroidManifest.xml` needs to be set to `persistAcrossReboots` for it to be called...but `MapActivity` is abstract, so you would need to set the attribute for its subclasses instead. in this case that would be `RecordingActivity`.

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <manifest>
       ...
       <application>
           ...
           <activity
               android:name=".RecordingActivity"
               android:persistableMode="persistAcrossReboots"/>
           ...
       </application>
       ...
   </manifest>
   ```

Comment: you can also declaration abstract fun for example doOnCreate in MapActivity and call this  fun in onCreate MapActivity and override this fun on anu Activity

Answer (score 0):

**Simple answer**: method `onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?)` and `onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?, persistentState: PersistableBundle?)` is not the same.

You need to override the same method, probably the first one.